# Keystroke working in IE not in Firefox

Tags: javascript, keystroke

I am just trying a simple application, to make the browser fullscreen. this is working for Internet Explorer, but not for firefox. 
Also I want to know, that can the same thing be done in Mac OC? do i have to make changes for Mac OS (using safari, firefox etc)

the code it below.

```
    <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function fullScreen()
{
var obj = new ActiveXObject("Wscript.shell"); 
obj.SendKeys("{F11}"); 
}

</script>


</head>

<body>
<form>
<input type="button" value="Click me!" onclick="fullScreen()" />
</form>

<p>By pressing the button above, a function will be called. The function will alert a message.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Regards
Zeeshan

Comment: I believe `ActiveXObject` is IE specific so it will never work on FF.

Comment: I don't know the default Mac keyboard shortcut, since I've overridden it with one of my choosing. There's no guarantee Windows users won't do the same. Relying on a simulated keystroke isn't terribly reliable.

Comment: @dplass: That is the answer i think, you should say that in an answer.

Comment: OK, not sure if it's a significant contribution to the question though.

Comment: I know ActiveXObject is for IE only. My question is how can I do the same thing that this code does in Firefox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All modern browsers, including IE8, allow the user to disallow a script's opening, moving or resizing a window. Also, IE allows you to prohibit activeX from untrusted (internet) sites, 
and the other browsers don't have native activeX.  so your solution may have very few successes, and a lot of errors and security warnings.

Of course, users can press f-11 anytime- maybe you could suggest they do so.

Comment: I get what you are saying, but still this is a requirement. And m still looking for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `ActiveXObject` is IE specific so it will never work on FF.